# Does the electromagnetic wave inside a waveguide experience matter wave behavior?

Tags: waves, waveguide

The electromagnetic wave inside a wave-guide has a longitudinal component besides the transverse one. Does this imply it has an effective mass? It is shown to do so by Wang in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0708/0708.3519.pdf. In such a case its mass will be connected with the inductance (L) and resistance (R) per unit lengths by  m= \frac{\hbar R}{c^2 L}. This latter relation is from the paper at 
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijleo.2017.05.002. How could this be plausible?

Answer (score 1):

I used to think of mass as stuff, and that massive particles must have something physically there that is conserved. Then along comes Albert Einstein, and he tells us:

$$ E = mc^2 $$.

Now some mass isn't *just* stuff (in my naive mental picture), it's *also* binding energy.

Of course Einstein threw in some dynamics:

$$ E = \sqrt{(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2} $$

So that's a frame dependent thing, but at least at zero-momentum (e.g., at rest) mass means you still have energy.

Then de Broglie tells us:

$$ E = \hbar\omega $$

$$ \vec p = \hbar \vec k $$

meaning:

$$ \hbar\omega = \sqrt{(\hbar kc)^2 + (mc^2)^2}  $$

Now that's starting to look like a dispersion relation:

$$ \omega  = \sqrt{ c^2k^2 + \omega_0^2}$$

with

$$\omega_0 = \frac{mc^2}{\hbar}  $$

All that means is that at zero wavenumber, there's finite frequency, which looks exactly like electromagnetism in a waveguide:

$$ \omega = \sqrt{ (kc)^2 + \omega^2_{cutoff}} $$

Now in a waveguide, Maxwell's equations still work. The photon is still massless, and $c$ is still the speed limit; however, interaction with the environment leads to the wave behaving as if it has an effective mass.

Now this revolutionizes my view of matter being stuff. It is no longer stuff. I now think of an electron as a quanta of the EM field that has finite energy at zero momentum solely because anywhere you have an electron, your have a non-zero Higgs field.

So rather than the pop-sci description of the Higgs field as a universal "molasses", I think of it as a universal wave guide that leads to finite frequency at infinite wavelength.

Of course, there are significant differences. Wave guides have a preferred direction, for instance. The Higgs field is of course a scalar, so that the mass isn't direction dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Classical electromagnetic radiation emerges from the confluence of zillion of photons, the elementary particles .

Two photons that are not collinear  have a summed [four vector](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) which has an invariant mass, the "length" of the four vector. A prime example is the pi0 [which decays into two photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion#Neutral_pion_decays). The pi0 has a mass and the summed four vectors of the decay have that mass, by conservation of energy and momentum.

Any ensemble of photons which are not collinear will have an invariant mass and a summed four vector describing it, so it is not surprising that in some configurations this mass is significant.